# A function $f$ is twice differentiable and $|f|\leq M_0$, $|f''|\leq M_2$, show that $|f'|\leq 2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I think I can conclude $f '$ is bounded implied by $f$ and $f''$ are both bounded straightly, but I'm stuck with proving $f'$ is bounded in this specific term. Can somebody help me?

Comment: sorry for the bad display of those terms cause i use this website for asking question first time, forgive me.